# Scraping a dynamic table with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the Trading Pools (Futures-Grid) table in the following link: https://www.binance.com/en/trading-bots using Selenium into a pandas dataframe. You can see the table when you scroll down a bit.

I am fairly beginner with selenium and I am unable to get the data into a dataframe. Could anyone please help me figure out the error?

**My attempt:**

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.binance.com/en/trading-bots"
driver_path = '/Volumes/Work&Study/chromedriver_mac_arm64' #current path

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

chrome_service = Service(driver_path)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=options)
browser.get(url)

# Give the js time to load the table
time.sleep(5)

# Click on the "Futures-Grid" button
futures_grid_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Futures-Grid")]'))
)
futures_grid_button.click()
print("Clicked on the Futures-Grid button")

# Wait for the table rows to load
rows_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".tableWrapper table tbody tr"))
)
print("Found {} rows".format(len(rows_element)))

headers = [
    "Rank/Market",
    "Direction",
    "Running Time",
    "ROI",
    "PNL(USD)",
    "Copy Popularity",
    "Action",
]

rows = []
for row_element in rows_element:
    row_html = row_element.get_attribute("outerHTML")
    row_soup = BeautifulSoup(row_html, "html.parser")
    cells = row_soup.find_all("td")
    cell_data = [cell.text.strip() for cell in cells]
    rows.append(cell_data)

binance_bots_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
binance_bots_df.head()

browser.quit()
```

For which I get the following error:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 31
     28 time.sleep(5)
     30 # Click on the "Futures-Grid" button
---> 31 futures_grid_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
     32     EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Futures-Grid")]'))
     33 )
     34 futures_grid_button.click()
     35 print("Clicked on the Futures-Grid button")

File ~/anaconda3/envs/trading/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py:95, in WebDriverWait.until(self, method, message)
     93     if time.monotonic() > end_time:
     94         break
---> 95 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x00000001052e5670 chromedriver + 4298352
1   chromedriver                        0x00000001052ddbbc chromedriver + 4266940
2   chromedriver                        0x0000000104f10758 chromedriver + 280408
3   chromedriver                        0x0000000104f4bb38 chromedriver + 523064
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000104f84080 chromedriver + 753792
5   chromedriver                        0x0000000104f3e2d0 chromedriver + 467664
6   chromedriver                        0x0000000104f3f354 chromedriver + 471892
...
13  chromedriver                        0x00000001052c93b4 chromedriver + 4182964
14  chromedriver                        0x00000001052d80f4 chromedriver + 4243700
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000199cebfa8 _pthread_start + 148
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000199ce6da0 thread_start + 8
```

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```py
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 100)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 100)
pd.set_option("display.width", 100)

url = "https://www.binance.com/en/trading-bots"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser.get(url)

# Click on the "Futures-Grid" button
futures_grid_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'tab-futuresGrid'))
)
futures_grid_button.click()
print("Clicked on the Futures-Grid button")

# Wait for the table rows to load
rows_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.body-row"))
)
print("Found {} rows".format(len(rows_element)))

headers = [
    "Rank/Market",
    "Direction",
    "Running Time",
    "ROI",
    "PNL(USD)",
    "Copy Popularity",
    "Action",
]

rows = []
for row_element in rows_element:
    cell_data = [i.text.replace('\n', ',') for i in row_element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class^="body-cell body-cell-"]')]
    # print(cell_data)
    rows.append(cell_data)

binance_bots_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
print(binance_bots_df)
```

output:

```py
Clicked on the Futures-Grid button
Found 10 rows
              Rank/Market Direction    Running Time       ROI  PNL(USD) Copy Popularity  Action
0       BNBUSDT,Perpetual   Neutral   1y 354d 3h 8m  1715.15%  5,145.47           19777  Create
1       ETHUSDT,Perpetual   Neutral  1y 354d 3h 29m  1679.91%  5,039.74           10083  Create
2       LITUSDT,Perpetual   Neutral    321d 15h 42m  1510.21%  7,550.78            4109  Create
3     4,XRPUSDT,Perpetual   Neutral     267d 4h 50m  1344.26%    263.47            2999  Create
4     5,XRPUSDT,Perpetual   Neutral    317d 16h 47m  1204.04%     29.98            2420  Create
5  6,PEOPLEUSDT,Perpetual      Long     322d 7h 55m  1085.46%    738.11             692  Create
6     7,ETHUSDT,Perpetual   Neutral    180d 22h 28m  1043.54%    104.35             593  Create
7     8,ETHUSDT,Perpetual   Neutral        235d 17h   971.66%    485.83             234  Create
8     9,XRPUSDT,Perpetual   Neutral    161d 19h 19m   939.93%     85.25             413  Create
9   10,LINKUSDT,Perpetual      Long    360d 20h 11m   910.09%    735.35             380  Create
```

Few Things to note:

1. you can locate the `Futures-Grid` button simply by using the `id`.
2. There is no need to use `time.sleep(5)` before it since you're already using `WebDriverWait`.
3. The rows of the target table lie in a `div` tag with class `body-row`. So you can simply use locate them with the `selector`. (`div.body-row`)
4. Now once you get all the row elements, all the cell data in each row lie in a `div` tag with class name starting with `body-cell body-cell-`. Here we can use the parse all the cells using partial class name (`div[class^="body-cell body-cell-"]`)

Comment: My god it works! But I had to make a small change, so that future readers could try either of the ways:
`#futures_grid_button.click()` #works for you
`browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", futures_grid_button)` #works for me But I also forgot to ask how I can select the drop down and choose less than 1 day option from the 'running time'. 

As it is a different task for which I have different errors, I will add that as new question in 5 min and mark this as completed. Thankyou!

Comment: I added the extra question, perhaps would be easy for you to identify my error. Thankyou in advance!