# Selecting dropdown to filter dynamic table using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the Trading Pools (Futures-Grid) table in the following link: https://www.binance.com/en/trading-bots using Selenium into a pandas dataframe. You can see the table when you scroll down a bit.

I was able to get the dataframe on the website on default view thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76198542/scraping-a-dynamic-table-with-selenium/76199109?noredirect=1#comment134376639_76199109)

However, I wanted to also click on the filter drop-down options available and select less than 1 day(≤1 Day) option from the `Running Time`section

**What I have attempted:**

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 100)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 100)
pd.set_option("display.width", 100)

url = "https://www.binance.com/en/trading-bots"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser.get(url)

# Click on the "Futures-Grid" button
futures_grid_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'tab-futuresGrid'))
)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", futures_grid_button)
print("Clicked on the Futures-Grid button")

# Locate the Running Time dropdown
running_time_dropdown = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[name="runningTime"]'))
)
print("Running Time dropdown found")

# Force click the Running Time dropdown
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", running_time_dropdown)

# Wait for the dropdown to be visible
dropdown_visible = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.bn-sdd-dropdown.showing'))
)
print("Dropdown is visible")

# Locate the select element inside the dropdown
select_element = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.bn-sdd-list')

# Create a Select object to interact with the dropdown
select = Select(select_element)

# Force click the "≤1 Day" option
one_day_option = select_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[normalize-space()='≤1 Day']")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", one_day_option)

# Wait for the table rows to load
rows_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.body-row"))
)
print("Found {} rows".format(len(rows_element)))

headers = [
    "Rank/Market",
    "Direction",
    "Running Time",
    "ROI",
    "PNL(USD)",
    "Copy Popularity",
    "Action",
]

rows = []
for row_element in rows_element:
    cell_data = [i.text.replace('\n', ',') for i in row_element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class^="body-cell body-cell-"]')]
    # print(cell_data)
    rows.append(cell_data)

binance_bots_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
print(binance_bots_df)

browser.quit()
```

But I get this error while attempting to filter using the dropdown menu:

```
Clicked on the Futures-Grid button
Running Time dropdown found
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 42
     39 browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", running_time_dropdown)
     41 # Wait for the dropdown to be visible
---> 42 dropdown_visible = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
     43     EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.bn-sdd-dropdown.showing'))
     44 )
     45 print("Dropdown is visible")
     47 # Locate the select element inside the dropdown

File ~/anaconda3/envs/trading/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py:95, in WebDriverWait.until(self, method, message)
     93     if time.monotonic() > end_time:
     94         break
---> 95 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000104d89670 chromedriver + 4298352
1   chromedriver                        0x0000000104d81bbc chromedriver + 4266940
2   chromedriver                        0x00000001049b4758 chromedriver + 280408
3   chromedriver                        0x00000001049efb38 chromedriver + 523064
4   chromedriver                        0x0000000104a28080 chromedriver + 753792
5   chromedriver                        0x00000001049e22d0 chromedriver + 467664
6   chromedriver                        0x00000001049e3354 chromedriver + 471892
...
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000104d6d3b4 chromedriver + 4182964
14  chromedriver                        0x0000000104d7c0f4 chromedriver + 4243700
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000199cebfa8 _pthread_start + 148
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000199ce6da0 thread_start + 8
```

I would appreciate your help in understanding how to work with these type of dropdowns to filter the dynamic table.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the drop down element is not build with `select` tag, so `Select` library cannot be used to interact with the drop down. And the drop down is build with `ul-li` tags.

Below is the code where I was able to select `≤1 Day` option.

```
#locate and click on Future Grid 
future_grid_option = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='leaderboard']//div[@id='tab-futuresGrid']/div")))
future_grid_option.click()

# Locate and click on Running time drop down
drop_down = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@aria-label='Running Time']")))
drop_down.click()

# Check if drop down is visible
options_list = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@name='runningTime']//ul")))

# Select ≤1 Day option from the list
option = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@name='runningTime']//li//div[text()='≤1 Day']")))
option.click()
```